# Solutions $x$ to the problem $A^T A x = A^T b$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Consider the problem $$A^* A x = A^* b$$
>   (call this equation (*)).
>
> (a) Explain the relationship between (*) and the problem $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|Ax - b\|^2$
>
> (b) Under what conditions on $A$, $A^{*}$, and $b$ is (*) guaranteed a solution? A unique solution?
>
> (c) Given $\epsilon > 0$ consider the problem $$(A^{*}A + \epsilon I)x_\epsilon = A^{*}b$$ (Call this (**).) Formulate an associated minimization problem, describe existence and uniqueness, and explain how $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} x_\epsilon$ is related to solutions of (*).

I'm pretty lost on this one.

Since $A$ is a real matrix of finite dimension, there's no problem with replacing $A^*$ with $A^T$, so that makes the problem a little less intimidating for me.

I took a shot at part (a), saying $$\|Ax - b\|^2 = (Ax - b)^T (Ax - b) = x^T A^T A x - x^T A^T b - b^T A x + b^T b$$

Thus, suppose then that (*) has a solution $x$. Then $$x^T A^T A x - x^T A^T b - b^T A x + b^T b = x^T A^T b - x^T A^T b - b^T A x + b^T b = b^T b - b^T A x = b^T(b - Ax)$$

In this case, $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|Ax - b\|^2 = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} b^T (b - Ax)$. This is not good; in principle this can be arbitrarily small (as in going to $-\infty$). So somewhere my reasoning is wrong. Perhaps I'm just not understanding this question.

For (b), would a condition be that $A$ have only 0 in its kernel (while requiring that $b \neq 0$? This doesn't seem like enough. I want to call upon invertibility but $A$ need not be a square matrix.

No idea what to do for (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Note that $||Ax-b||^2$ is always bounded below by zero for every choice of $x$.
- Note that $\min_{x}||Ax-b||^2$ is a convex problem. Thus KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient. In simple words, differentiating this w.r.to $x$ and setting that to zero should be a necessary and sufficient condition for the solution to satisfy (strictly speaking, there are addition conditions).
- Use above two, can you solve (a)?
- Can you comment on the rank of $A^TA$ given the rank of $A$. Given that and the facts above can you solve (b)?
- Can you do the same for the optimization problem $$\min_{x}||Ax-b||^2+\epsilon||x||_2^2$$
- Can you convince yourself that $(A^TA+\epsilon I)$ is invertible? (Further Hint: Use SVD of $A=U\Sigma U^H$)
- Now do you see the relative between (c) and the optimization problem stated above. When $\epsilon \to 0$, can you comment on the optimization problem above?
- After all is done, can you look upon Tikhonov Regularization?